# Laravel Many to Many Relationship with 2 foreign key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables - users, graduation_institutes, graduation_degrees

I defined a pivot table - graduation_degree_user

graduation_degree_user table has data like below -

id--------doctor_id--------graduation_degree_id----------graduation_institute_id---------year

In my User model, I defined relation like below -

```
public function graduations(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User\GraduationDegree')->withTimestamps();
}
```

In my controller, I m doing -

```
if($request->has('graduations')){
    $user->graduations()->sync($request->graduations);
}
return $user->graduations;
```

Where graduations is an array which contains multiple object.

I am getting the following response -

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "degree": "MD",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 2,
            "graduation_degree_id": 3,
            "graduation_institute_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-12-01T07:54:23.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-12-01T07:54:23.000000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "degree": "MBBS",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "pivot": {
            "user_id": 2,
            "graduation_degree_id": 4,
            "graduation_institute_id": 2,
            "created_at": "2020-12-01T07:54:24.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-12-01T07:54:24.000000Z"
        }
    }
]
```

In response, I am getting **graduation_institute_id** but I also want the name of the institute which is a field 'institute' defined in **graduation_institutes** table.